# wrote function to calculate set bits from 0 to n,

Tags: c++, recursion, bit-manipulation

in  this function i check if the no. is one less than the power of 2 and then make recursive calls for 2^b - 1 and n - 2^b(this call keeps happening till the no. here is one less than a power of 2)
now I know the code is wrong but why does it give segmentation fault.

```
 int countSetBits(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 0;
    int b = floor(log2(n));
    if ( (n + 1) & n == 0 ) {
        return (1<<b)* floor(log2(n + 1));
    }
    return (n - 1<<b + 1) + countSetBits(n - 1<<b) + countSetBits(1<<b - 1);
    
    }
```

Comment: How many calls to `countSetBits` do you expect in the stack at once?

Comment: If you have a C++20 compiler, use [`std::popcount`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/popcount)

Comment: How do you expect `( (n + 1) & n == 0 )` to be interpreded? As `( ((n + 1) & n) == 0 )`, or as `( (n + 1) & (n == 0) )`? Operator precedence scares me in these few lines :)

Comment: To add to he ways this code is ill-advised.  For `n==0xFFFFFFFF`, `n+1 == 0`.

Comment: @rturrado the first one, i'll correct it at once

Answer (score 1):

The infinite number of (recursive) function calls causes [stack overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow). The program's stack has become too large and tries to "overflow" into the next memory segment. This is not allowed, and hence the segfault.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for the errors are two-fold:

1. You are using floating point numbers, in floor and log2. Those are imprecise and won't give you the exactness you need for this task.
2. You are left shifting your numbers (making them bigger). I didn't follow the logic you wanted, but usually, the approach is to take the least bits out and then right-shift the numbers (`>>`)

Lastly, either use a debugger, or introduce debug `cout`s to see what your program is doing, that will make it overall much easier.